# iphone app with Game Center

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I am fresher for Game Center, and I cant understand from where to start, so can anyone help me for Game center,what should I refer first? Create app or create an App Id on the Itunes Connect??

Comment: CHeck this link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-1/

Comment: you can find answer of this question on following link,               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948449/how-can-i-make-an-online-2-player-game-in-cocos2d-x/13948848#13948848

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create the app id ,based on that app id.

Now in itunes connect create new app,after you have created the app you would be show option for manage game center select and use as you want.

Now if you can use that bundle id in the app where using Game Center.

feel free to ask if not understood.